# Copy columns to another csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a csv table and I want to copy some columns to another csv table.

```
import csv
path1='1.csv'
path2='2.csv'
outdata=[]
with open(path1,'rb') as input ,open (path2,'wb') as output:
    reader=csv.reader(input)
    writer=csv.writer(output,delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        outdata.append(row[0])
        outdata.append(row[1])
    write.writerows(outdata)
```

Here is my original table(some cells are null):

```
 a b c d f
 1   3   5
   e   t
 5   4   6
```

but the new table is just in one column:

```
a
1

5
b

e
```

what I want:

```
a b
1  
  e
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation is slightly complex. In your case, space is both **delimiter** & a **column** entry!! AFAIK, this would definitely confuse the Python interpreter. See if you can avoid that.

I have assumed that ' ' (i.e., space) is **not** a column entry instead it is '' (i.e., empty string). Then your 1.csv becomes:

```
$> cat 1.csv 
a b c d f
1  3  5
 e  t
5  4  6
```

If that is your scenario, then this code will work:

```
import csv
path1='1.csv'
path2='2.csv'
outdata = []
input_file = open(path1,'rb')
output = open (path2,'wb')

reader=csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=' ')
writer=csv.writer(output,delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:
    print("row: ", row)
    outdata.append([row[0], row[1]])
print(outdata)
writer.writerows(outdata)
```

So couple of changes from your script:

1. You have to specify the delimiter for reader as well. The default delimiter is ','
2. Since you use `csv.writerows()`, the input is a list of list & each list is a row. So, prepare a list of list & you will see the values properly.

Finally, the output of the above python script is exactly as you wanted:

```
$> cat 2.csv
('row: ', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'])
('row: ', ['1', '', '3', '', '5'])
('row: ', ['', 'e', '', 't'])
('row: ', ['5', '', '4', '', '6'])
[['a', 'b'], ['1', ''], ['', 'e'], ['5', '']]
a b
1 
 e
5
```

I have added a lot of prints so that you can understand the script better. :)

Comment: It still wrong, which says outdata.append([row[0],row[1]]). IndexError: list index out of rang. I think we cannot write like [row[0],row[1]] when we use append

Comment: @ZexiangFan: What is your python version? I used python-2.6.5 and the code above is the copy-paste of my working file.